# Does $f$ uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty)$ imply that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Does $f$ uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty)$ imply that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists?

I think that this is true. Because $f$ u.c. implies $f$ has bounded derivative. Can someone help me confirm this hypothesis?

Thanks

Comment: $\sin x{{{}}}$?

Comment: oh that is a counterexample. oops thanks

Comment: wait so then if $f$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$ AND the $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then is it true that $f$ is uniformly continuous? this must be true then, right?

Comment: Yes that is true stack.

Answer (score 0):

No—consider the function $\sin(x)$.

It does not converge because it oscillates at infinity, but it clearly is uniformly continuous, being differentiable everywhere and having bounded derivative.

Comment: so then if $f$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$ AND the $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then is it true that $f$ is uniformly continuous? this must be true then, right?

Comment: @stackofhay42 Sorry, this is not related to your question directly but I've seen your trend in the past of never accepting an answer to any of your question. If an answer is complete and clear your doubt you should consider accepting it so that your question will be marked as _answered_.

Answer (score 0):

The function $$f : x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$$

is uniformly continuous at $[0,+\infty)$ but $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$$